# Vue - Limiting child component only with variables passed in props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

Someone has already done something like:
- Block the `child-component` from accessing 'variables' other than those passed by`props`?

Goal :
- In twig, I can say to the template which methods and variables will be available for use, I wanted to do the same idea using the component that can be customizable

Type a parameter: `isolate: true`

Some users will be able to create their own components, I do not want them to access the parent components in order to "break / cheat" the behavior that I implemented.

I just want them to enjoy the data I'm going to pass on

As the concept of components is able to work "alone", they do not need to issue events, they do not have to trigger callbacks or change the state of the app in any moment .
These users have to just receive the data, be creative and do something that I "no time" can not implement for everyone!

Therefore, they can do whatever they think is best and the way they like it, as long as they do not change / interfere with the basic rules of APP.

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Can you show us what you already have, it'll make it easier to help you.

Comment: a child component can always access it's parent via `.$parent` or even `.$root` And of course a child can access global variables as well.

Comment: My problem is that I do not want the child component to access the parent component, it has to only receive the properties and work with them, without sending events and nothing.